# Writing and copying Text files

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception, filewriter, printwriter

I have an assignment to :write a program that reads a file and writes a copy of the file to another file with line numbers inserted. I am not sure what to do at the end of the code at the "for(int i =0; i < lines.length; i++)" part. what do I need to do for the "lines" part and how do I add the line numbers?
Thanks

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question43 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("Chapter 11Assign43.txt") );


    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("FileOut.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileOut);

    String []array = new String[10];

    int indx = 0;
    while(fileIn.hasNext( ) )
    {
        array[indx] = fileIn.nextLine( );
    }

    fileIn.close();

    int num = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        output.println(num+"\t"+array[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just do something like,

```
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    output.println(i+"\t"+array[i]);
}
```

Just use the variable `i`, since it will increment with each loop anyway.

Comment: the "lines" word is where I am getting an error though, says "cant find variable".

Comment: @Torre I switched it to array.length, I think that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Want to try this ...

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infile"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfile"));
    String line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(++lineNumber + " " + line);
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.io.LineNumberReader to count lines

```
    LineNumberReader lr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("file1"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2"));
    String line;
    while((line = lr.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(lr.getLineNumber() + " " + line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
```